# Which function will be called a second time when a firebase transcation fails the first time?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#transactions) claims:

> A function calling a transaction (transaction function) might run more
> than once if a concurrent edit affects a document that the transaction
> reads.

It is unclear *exactly* which function will run twice when there is a concurrent edit. In the example below, `outerFunc` calls the `runTranscation` method, so a literal interpretation of the documentation would imply that that `outerFunc` may be called twice.

However, this seems like a strange implementation, and I suspect that the docs mean to say that `innerFunc` may be called more than once when there is a concurrent edit.

```js
import { runTransaction } from "firebase/firestore";

function outerFunc () {
  console.log('outerFunction');
  try {
    await runTransaction(db, async function innerFunc(transaction) {
      const sfDoc = await transaction.get(sfDocRef);
      if (!sfDoc.exists()) {
        throw "Document does not exist!";
      }

      const newPopulation = sfDoc.data().population + 1;
      transaction.update(sfDocRef, { population: newPopulation });
    });
    console.log("Transaction successfully committed!");
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("Transaction failed: ", e);
  }
}
```

Could `outerFunc` be called twice when there is a concurrent edit as the doc imply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way the Firestore SDK can invoke your `outerFunc` (let alone multiple times), but your `innerFunc` callback may be called multiple times by the Firestore SDK indeed.

If you find the documentation confusing, please file feedback on the page itself. There should be a link for that at the bottom right.